# Android, change fonts on a final text view

Tags: android, fonts, textview, final

I want to change the font on a text view
But the tv is modified at the pression of a button, and i define "final" the tv, and the app crashed...
what i can do it?

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/HeroQuest.ttf");
final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

This code work if tv is not final

Comment: Could you provide a stack trace ?

Comment: Attach please a stacktrace, but I'm pretty sure that "final" is not a cause of your crash. It's really doesn't change anything.

Comment: i found a solution
public class Personaggi extends Activity {
 TextView tv;
 
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  
  //change font
  Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/HeroQuest.ttf");
  tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.corpo);
  
  tv.setTypeface(tf);
  
  
               
     View.OnClickListener gestore = new View.OnClickListener() {
         
      public void onClick(View view) { 
//here put thw switch for the button, and i can use the tv without declare it final

Comment: i' posting the solution... i declared the tv as global

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/HeroQuest.ttf");
TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv1.setTypeface(tf);
final TextView tv = tv1;
....
```

Comment: i found a solution public class Personaggi extends Activity { TextView tv; @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.main); //change font Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/HeroQuest.ttf"); tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.corpo); tv.setTypeface(tf); View.OnClickListener gestore = new View.OnClickListener() { public void onClick(View view) { //here put thw switch for the button, and i can use the tv without declare it final

Answer (score 0):

Define your `TextView` as **field**

i.e
    private TextView tv;

```
if u need more clarification on crash.paste the code in your OnClicklistener
```